# is there any way to access the value of a variable if an error occurs in the function in python?

Tags: python, jupyter

This is my function and an error occurred during its execution. so is there any way that I can access the values of variables before the line where the error occurred?
like here the error occurred on "`df = DataFrame({'real_rating': real_rating, 'predicted_rating': predicted_rating})`" so i want to access the values of `real_rating` and `predicted_rating` variables?

```
def calc_MAE_system(targetClusterTestUserDict,final_clusters):
    real_rating=[]
    predicted_rating=[]

    for i in range(0,length):
      real_rating.append(test.iloc[i]['rating'])
      temp_rating=predict_rating(final_clusters,test.iloc[i]['userId'],userBelongsToCluster,test.iloc[i]['movieId'],temp_df_rating)
      predicted_rating.append(temp_rating)


    df = DataFrame({'real_rating': real_rating, 'predicted_rating': predicted_rating})
    df.to_csv("rating_comparison_online_phase.csv", sep='\t')


    if(length != 0):
      mae=sum/length
    else:
      mae=0

    return mae
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use 'try' and 'except'. If the code in the 'try' does not work, it uses the code in the 'except' instead.
E.g.

```
try:
    df = DataFrame({'real_rating': real_rating, 'predicted_rating': predicted_rating})
except:
    print("Error: real_rating = " + str(real_rating) + ", predicted_rating = " + str(predicted_rating))
```

If the dataframe could not be created, it would print something like:

```
Error: real_rating = xxxxx, predicted_rating = yyyy
```

Comment: yes, but for that i have to again run the code but i want to access now itself?

Comment: Of course. If you're looking to get the values of these from a previous run now, you would have had to have them logged somewhere

Comment: one of the other way which i tried was, by declaring function variables to global. e.g `global var_name`